# Replace characters within an attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several options values (attribute `value`) that have spaces,

```
<option value="Divers RF" class="">Divers RF</option>

<option value="France Bleu" class="">France Bleu</option>
```

How can I replace the space with a _ in the value?

So the result would be

```
<option value="Divers_RF" class="">Divers RF</option>
<option value="France_Bleu" class="">France Bleu</option>
```

and not only for these two options but for all options that have spaces in them.

Comment: could you be more clear... like whether you statically want _ in values or you want to change it with jquery events

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('option').val(function(i,v){
   return v.replace(/\s/g, '_');
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/YQWGw/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("option").each(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(val.replace(/ /g, '_'));
}
```

thanks to @Fender, replace should be greedy

**EDIT**: adopted to replace value instead of text content

Comment: you should use `$(this).text(val.replace(/ /g, '_'));` to replace all occurences

Comment: I would look more closely at the question.  I believe the OP wants the attributes changed, not the text within the option element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option").each(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g, '_'));
});
```