# jQuery replace space with _ in options class

Tags: jquery

I have several options classes that have spaces

```
<option value="Divers RF" class="Divers RF">Divers RF</option>
<option value="France Bleu" class="France Bleu">France Bleu</option>
```

How can i replace the space with a _ in the class?

so the result would be:

```
<option value="Divers RF" class="Divers_RF">Divers RF</option>
<option value="France Bleu" class="France_Bleu">France Bleu</option>
```

and not only for theses 2 classes but for all classes that have spaces in it.

Comment: You want the second option example to be `France_Bleu`, right?

Comment: yes sorry i have made the correction

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Why are you even putting that data in the class in the first place? Class is a list of classes separated by spaces, it's pretty odd to be removing the spaces - if you have any other classes in there you can really mess things up.

Comment: It would probably help to understand why you're wanting to do so.

Comment: @Ariel, yeah i know, the reason i do that is that i'm using a jQuery plugin to chain selects and i need the class without the spaces :)

Comment: This question looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812971/jquery-replace-characters-within-an-attribute which you asked a little bit ago.  How are they different?

Comment: yeah cause i'm a beginner and i'm still experimenting with jQuery :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("option").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("class", $(this).attr("class").replace(/ /g, '_'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('option').each(function() {
     if($(this).attr('class') != "")
     {
          var className = $(this).attr('class');
          $(this).attr("class","");
          className = className.replace(/ /g,"_");
          $(this).addClass(className);
     }
});
```

Comment: Did you test it? I don't think removeClass will not remove a class containing a space in the name, because a space is the class separator.